# Ошибка matchTemplate из OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть работающая функция переводящая скриншот экрана в объект типа Mat из OpenCV.

```
Mat Screen()  
{
    HDC rabstol = GetDC(NULL); 
    HDC novaDC = CreateCompatibleDC(rabstol); 

    HBITMAP BitmapStola = CreateCompatibleBitmap(rabstol, 1920, 1080);

    SelectObject(novaDC, BitmapStola); 
    BitBlt(novaDC, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, rabstol, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = 920;
    bi.biHeight = -500;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    Mat mat = Mat(500, 920, CV_8UC4); 
    GetDIBits(novaDC, BitmapStola, 0, 500, mat.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    DeleteObject(BitmapStola);
    DeleteDC(novaDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, rabstol);
    
    return mat;
}
```

передача результата этой функции в первый параметр matchTemplate() вызывает ошибку:

```
Mat templ, result;
Mat img = Screen();
matchTemplate(img, templ, result, TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);
```

Но если img сначала записать на диск а потом прочитать, все работает:

```
Mat templ, result;
Mat img = Screen();
imwrite("D:\\1.jpg", mat);
img = imread("D:\\1.jpg");
matchTemplate(img, templ, result, TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);
```

я предполагаю дело в типе вектора Mat. Создавая функцией Screen() я делаю неподходящим для matchTemplate(). а когда читаю с диска то функция imread() конвертирует как нужно.

**вопрос, можно ли конвертировать результат Screen() без записи на диск? спасибо**

Comment: *"вызывает ошибку"* - какую?

Comment: CV_8UC4 - там правда 4, а не 3 канала?

Comment: @user7860670
Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу

Comment: @AlexAlex
если изменить на CV_8UC4, в мат возвращается черный экран. да, а ошибка пропадает.
 
я пробовал конвертировать. например: 
img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);

та же ошибка

Comment: В таком случае его надо отладить, выяснив где именно оно возникает и почему. И привести в вопросе хотя бы стактрейс. Отладку лучше проводить используя санитайзер памяти какой-нибудь, чтобы быстрее отловить место, где происходит повреждение памяти.

Comment: @user7860670
место я определил: функция matchTemplate() при обработке своего 1го параметра, обращается не по адресу. 
это изза того что обьект типа Mat имеет неподходящий формат. но я не могу найти в средствах библиотеки OpenCV способов конвертировать в подходящий.

например читая файл с диска в обьект Mat или изменив функцию которая делает скрин, ошибка не возникает.

Answer (score 0):

спасибо всем кто участвовал, и подталкивал к решению. ответ нашелся:

функцией `cvtColor(img, img, COLOR_BGRA2BGR);` нужно удалить 4й канал, который возвращался из функции скриншота.

в документации OpenCV по требованиям первого параметра функции matchTemplate() написано только 8 или 32 бит. про каналы ничего (